# Is a TBC required for converting VHS home videos to digital format?

Tags: video-recording, conversion, vhs, analog, digitisation

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-buying-a-vcr-for-digitising-old-vhs-tapes). The DigitalFAQ forum, whose members seem to know a lot about this particular topic, say about TBCs:

> You must have some form of TBC, it's not optional. You can try to scrimp by with an ES10/15 unit, for under £100. It's minimalist, and not actually a TBC. But if funds matter more than quality, it's probably the only avenue if really pinching pennies.

What exactly is a TBC, and do I really need one to get decent quality from a VHS capture?

Comment: related: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32492/what-causes-audio-sync-drift-when-digitizing-vhs